# Wildfly 22 - WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: wildfly

In Wildfly 22.0.0 or later, the following error occurs.

```
2022-08-24 15:59:43,380 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "shcm")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
"org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.default-server", 
"org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.default-server"
],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => 
["org.wildfly.clustering.web.route-locator.\"shcmupdate.war\" is missing
[org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.default-server,
org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.default-server]"]
```

}

I have clustering configuration in web.xml and jboss-web.xml in my application.
if use standalone-ha.xml, it works normally.
but subsystem error occurs when standalone.xml is used from Wildfly 22.0.0 or later.
What changes were made in Wildfly 22?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was never supported to be enable for non-`standalone.xml` builds, so it was likely removed in [this PR](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/13839/files#diff-9a272ab7d21cd902d57ccde4a9b818dfecd4e8af8c39651b129d33a2506d9d3dL18) ([`distributable-web.xml`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/c5e18f5a8e3cac7addabd980bdf910b6bb1cb1ae/ee-feature-pack/galleon-common/src/main/resources/feature_groups/distributable-web.xml#L18) includes an Infinispan cache that `distributable-web-local.xml` does not).

The [WildFly HA docs](https://docs.wildfly.org/22/High_Availability_Guide.html) should be able to help you migrate to WF 22.

Answer (score 0):

This was really unfortunate decision. It is killing EAP v. 7.4.5 (7.4.6) deployments.

I had replication-config as a part of jboss-web.xml file, that causes this issue. The application runs in ha mode in production, so the configuration is needed, but for the development there is no reason to maintain the whole cluster so I was happy the setting was ignored.

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd"
           version="10.0">

 <context-root>my-application</context-root>
     <!--
     <replication-config>
         <replication-granularity>ATTRIBUTE</replication-granularity>
     </replication-config> -->   
 </jboss-web>
```

Commented out configuration is the part, that was causing the issue.

Comment: The problem is now being solved under https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-23936